# ASM Tree API insert into InsnList giving StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I'm trying to follow the delegation example on page 112 of the ASM user manual (http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf). So far I have something that looks like this:

```
class MyMethodAdapter extends MethodVisitor {
    MethodVisitor next;
    public MyMethodAdapter(int access, String name, String desc,
                           String signature, String[] exceptions, MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(
            Opcodes.ASM4,
            new MethodNode(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions)
        );
        next = mv;
    }

    @Override public void visitEnd() {
        MethodNode mn = (MethodNode) mv;

        mn.instructions.insert(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, "runtime/Recorder", "checkBytecodes", "()V"));


        mn.accept(next);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, it fails:

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at ../../../src/share/instrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 844

Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

This only happens when the `mn.instructions.insert(` line is present, so presumably the rest of my transformation pipeline works. Is there anything I'm missing here? I'm literally putting my transformation in the `// put your transformation code here` area marked out in the manual, and the resultant error is completely unintelligible.

`add()`ing the instruction to the end of the method's instruction list seems to run fine, but that's not what I want. I want the new static call to be first thing in the method body.

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack trace it is hard to say if this is related to ASM API.

You can still insert your call at the beginning of instruction list using:

```
mn.instructions.insertBefore(mn.instructions.getFirst(), 
    new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, "runtime/Recorder", "checkBytecodes", "()V"));
```